How to create ASP.NET Core MVC web app project in Visual Studio with other ASP.NET Core web app Nuget package
I'm creating an ASP.NET Core 7.0 MVC project VS. This project is my nuget project:
Example image
I want to use this nuget project as a theme in another project. I need all wwwroot files to you second project.
However, the wwwroot file is not added to the second project (other files same). When I run the second project, it runs the layout file but does not see the wwwroot files.
I tried to add contentFiles in nuspec file but that didn't work.

What do you mean by "NuGet project"?

I turn the project into a nuget package by using the "Generate Nuget package on build" option in the properties section.

.NET 7.0 is already out of support - I would strongly recommend not using it to build anything new - use .NET 8.0 instead! (that'll be supported to Nov 2026)
